# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Directive')

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive, angular2-directives

[image]

Hi, I am using Angular: 11.0.7 version.

I have issue with dropdown which is not showing after refresh of the page, and the error which I get is in the picture that I post, and it refers to HTML file.

When I navigate for the first time to the page, everything is working fine, but when I try to refresh the page, this error appears, but it can happen that after 20 times of refreshing the page, sometime it can load as it should be, and it works fine, but that is 1 in milion times, and in some cases it throw me error on some other HTML file with the same error message.

Because it said that I am reading Directive and it is undefined, I want to let you know that I am using [ngSwitch], *ngIf from built-in Directives.

Parent component:

```
<tabs
[tabItems]="tabItems"  
(selectedTab)="selectedTab($event)"
></tabs>

<ng-container [ngSwitch]="appName">
  <child1-component //// error is refering to this line most of the time
    *ngSwitchCase="'SomeAppName'"
    [appGuid]="appTabGuid"
    [userGuid]="userGuid"
  ></child1-component>
  <p *ngIf="loaded && apps.length == 0">No data</p>
</ng-container>
```

Child1 component html:

```
<spinner>Loading...<spinner>
<div class="work-noti-container">
  <div class="work-noti-container__form-container__desc">
    Please select
  </div>
  <ng-container *ngIf="pastDue && !isSimpleVersion">
    <div class="work-noti-container__form-container">
      <div class="work-noti-container__form-container__title">Work Past Due</div>
      <child2-of-child1-component
        [type]="work.WorkPastDue"
        [events]="eventsSubject.asObservable()"
        [valid]="valid1"
        (validChange)="valid1 = $event; isDisabled()"
        (formSave)="getFormData($event)"
      ></child2-of-child1-component>
    </div>
    <hr />
  </ng-container>
// START BLOCK OF CODE THAT IT SHOULD SHOW AFTER REFRESH
  <ng-container *ngIf="ready">
    <div class="work-noti-container__form-container_m-t-25">
      <div class="work-noti-container__form-container__title">Work Ready</div>
      <child2-of-child1-component ////////// Some time it throws error here
        [type]="workType.WorkReady"
        [events]="eventsSubject"
        [valid]="valid2"
        (validChange)="valid2 = $event; isDisabled()"
        (formSave)="getFormData($event)"
      ></child2-of-child1-component>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
// END BLOCK OF CODE THAT IT SHOULD SHOW AFTER REFRESH
  <ng-container *ngIf="other && !isSimpleVersion">
    <hr />
    <div class="work-noti-container__form-container">
      <div class="work-noti-container__form-container__title">
        Work Other
      </div>
      <child2-of-child1-component
        [type]="workType.WorkItemCreated"
        [events]="eventsSubject.asObservable()"
        [valid]="valid3"
        (validChange)="valid3 = $event; isDisabled()"
        (formSave)="getFormData($event)"
      ></child2-of-child1-component>
    </div>
  </ng-container>  
</div>
```

Child2 of Child1:

```
 <form [formGroup]="dynamicForm" class="pm-item">
  <div>
    <dropdown
      name="FrequencyPastDue+type"
      [id]="'frequencyPastDue' + type"
      [dropdownType]="'text-list'"
      [dropdownItems]="frequencyItems"
      [label]="'Frequency'"
      [textField]="'label'"
      [valueField]="'label'"
      [variant]="'light'"
      [width]="'270px'"
      (selectedValueChanged)="onChangeFrequency($event)"
      [isRequiredField]="true"
      [selectedValue]="f.frequency.value"
    ></dropdown>
  </div>
  <div *ngIf="f.time != undefined">
    <dropdown
      name="timePastDue+type"
      [id]="'timePastDue' + type"
      [dropdownType]="'text-list'"
      [dropdownItems]="timeItems"
      [label]="'Select Time'"
      [valueField]="'label'"
      [textField]="'label'"
      [variant]="'light'"
      [width]="'270px'"
      (selectedValueChanged)="selectedValueChanged($event, 'time')"
      [selectedValue]="f.time.value"
      [isRequiredField]="true"
    ></dropdown>
  </div>
<div *ngIf="f.day != undefined">
    <dropdown
      name="DayPastDue+type"
      [id]="'dayPastDue' + type"
      [dropdownType]="'text-list'"
      [dropdownItems]="dayItems"
      [label]="'Select Day'"
      [valueField]="'label'"
      [textField]="'label'"
      [variant]="'light'"
      [width]="'270px'"
      (selectedValueChanged)="selectedValueChanged($event, 'day')"
      [selectedValue]="f.day.value"
      [isRequiredField]="true"
    ></dropdown>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: unless a stackblitz is provided where its reproducible, its hard to tell whats wrong here.

Comment: This will be very difficult to provide code on stackblitz, one of many reasons are that this is micro-frontend application, that is integrated into parent application. And in general, app is very slow, it has low performance.